# Split an 1D array into N clusters but retain order

Tags: time-series, clustering, k-means

I am trying to split an array into N=6 parts which share some similarity but it is important that they retain the order they are in.
An example is:

```
array([ 8.96945455,  1.88181818,  8.99636364, 13.37109091,  0.83636364,
        5.82654545, -6.34636364, -5.91454545, 14.50309091, -0.69090909,
       -0.88327273, -4.74272727, 11.14309091,  0.23327273,  9.48836364,
       31.36163636, 22.88381818])
```

[image]

A possible split would then look like

[0-5,6-7,8,9-11,12-14,15-16]

How can I achieve that?
I looked into k means clustering but I haven't found out how to retain the order. Is it possible? Are there other algorithms which help me?
I am thankful for any advice.
Also, if there is an implementation in python or r please let me know.

**EDIT**

Could it be that I am better helped without using a clustering algorithm and just try to segment based on the previous value? If (x[i-1]-x[i])< some value (maybe std?)
and if I am over my desired number of clusters merge the M most similar clusters until I have N?

Comment: Is this time series data? Are you trying to do changepoint / novelty  detection?

Comment: Yes it is time series data. I have 24 data points (hourly data) but omit some because they don't contribute much. The resulting data is still connected though. I usually omit 0-6 or 0-7 depending. The y is a performance indicator. I want to create similar performing subsets and do something with them, but they need to remain ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clustering is the wrong terminology here. These methods assume there is no order to your input data points.

What you are trying to do is **segmentation** of a series, piecewise linear regression, change point detection or something like that.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-series_segmentation

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_detection

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I will look into it